# Understanding definition of Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello and happy holidays,

The definition of linear independence in my notes is:

(Linear independence of functions). The functions $y_i : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C^n, i \in \{1,...,k\}$ are said to be *linearly independent* if, given $c_i \in \mathbb C, i \in \{1,...,k\}$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i y_i(t) = 0 \text{ for all } t \in \mathbb R \text{ implies } c_1 = c_2 = \cdots = c_k = 0.$$

Now I understand this. But in my notes in an example, they prove linear independence by proving the constants are equal to $0$ for only one value of $t$. Why can you do this? Do you just assume that the sum equals $0$ for all $t$ as in the definition?

Comment: Linear indpendence of functions is basically saying that you can't scale the functions up by any amount and sum them up to get a function that's $0$ everywhere. Summing functions basically just involves summing them at all points, which is why you have quantification over $t$.

Comment: Oh, so because of the nature of adding functions you are in essence adding the functions for all points?

Comment: Yeah. I mean, when you learn addition, it's usally $2+2=4$ kind of stuff. But what does it mean to add two functions? The "sensible" definition is indeed to add all the points. So $f+g$ is the function $h$ such that for all $x$, $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. Notice we had to introduce a quantifier to define our new function. That's all its doing above. If they'd defined addition over functions elsewhere like I just did then they could have used this instead and got rid of the quantification over all $t$.

Comment: The existence of $t_0$ such that $\sum_ic_i(t_0)=0\implies c_1=...=c_k$ is $sufficient$  to imply linear independence of the functions but not $necessary.$..... For an example of non-necessity  let $ n=1,\;k=2, \;y_1(r)=e^r, \;y_2(r)=e^{-r}.$ Then $y_1, y_2$ are linearly independent functions but  $\{y_1(t),y_2(t)\}$  is never  a linearly independent subset of  $\Bbb C=\Bbb C^n.$

Answer (score 2):

In the definition you are given that the $y_i$ are linearly independent if you have that

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^k c_iy_i(t) = 0 \ \ \forall t\in\mathbb{R}  \quad\implies \quad c_i = 0 \ \  \forall i \in \{1, \ldots , k\}
$$

So when showing linear independence you will start by assuming the LHS of the implication. By this assumption you have that the sum above is zero for all $t$ and the goal is to show that from this assumption all the $c_i = 0$. You are free to use whatever specific value of $t$ that you want in order to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

Linear independence of a bunch of objects always says that you can't scale the objects by any amounts and add them all together to get $0$, with the exception of where you're scaling by $0$.

Before we can apply this to functions, we have to define some things:

1. Addition. Given functions $f, g, h$: $h = f+g$ iff $\forall x \cdot h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$.
2. Scaling. Given functions $f, h$ and scalar $c$, $h = cf$ iff $\forall x \cdot h(x) = cf(x)$.
3. $0$ as a function can be defined as the function such that for all $0(x) = 0$ for every value of $x$. That is, it is the function that's $0$ everywhere.

Then say we have functions $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k$. These are linearly independent iff for all scalars $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k$:

$$c_1f1 + c2_f2 + \ldots + c_kf_k = 0 \implies \forall i \cdot c_i = 0$$

All that says is, the only way to arrive at the function that's $0$ everywhere through a combination of any of these functions is to set all the coefficients to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So to clarify, because of "1." and the fact that addition holds for all x, you only need to show linear independence for one value of the function? I sort of understood the rest, that's the confusing bit in my opinion.

Comment: @jacobelm NOT QUITE! I think your confusion arises from the use of quantifiers (e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)). We're quantifying over all values of the function in our definitions which means every value of the superposition of functions is the addition of the values from the original two functions. Not just one value! The $x$ we use is arbitrary- it represents any value- by quantifying, we are saying we want to consider the statement for all values of $x$.

Comment: @jacobelm once you've got your head around quantifiers, the key point is this. When you scale a function, you multiply all its values by the same amount. This is all you can control in a linear combination of the functions. You can't warp the functions in any other way. If the functions are sufficiently different in shape, then no matter how you compose them linearly, you'll never get $0$. This is what linear independence says.